# And/or keyword when search with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm now writing a searching application on C#/ASP.NET.

User inputs a keyword into a textbox, and then my app finds appropriate results from SQL Server through ADO.NET.

I want to implement ability to search using AND/OR keyword in my application.

For example:

Now my users can input a keyword such as "Cisco". Now they want to search with "Cisco AND Microsoft" or "Cisco OR Microsoft"

How can I do this?

Comment: that's a bit vague... fancy tightening up the question a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Full text search and contains?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms513993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use SQL Server for search? Consider [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

Answer (score 0):

check out [Erland Sommarskog - Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html)